# Delphi 2010 RTTI and Interface fields

Tags: delphi, rtti

I have a problem with the properties of IInterface type.
I don't know how to assign values to these properties using RTTI

Here's an example:.

```
program Project2;

uses
  Forms, RTTI, Windows, TypInfo;
{$R *.res}

type
  ITestInterfacedClass = interface
    ['{25A5B554-667E-4FE4-B932-A5B8D9052A17}']
    function GetA: ITestInterfacedClass;
    procedure SetA(const Value: ITestInterfacedClass);
    property A: ITestInterfacedClass read GetA write SetA;
    function GetB: ITestInterfacedClass;
    procedure SetB(const Value: ITestInterfacedClass);
    property B: ITestInterfacedClass read GetB write SetB;
  end;


  TTestInterfacedClass = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestInterfacedClass)
  private
    FA: ITestInterfacedClass;
    FB: ITestInterfacedClass;

    function GetA: ITestInterfacedClass;
    function GetB: ITestInterfacedClass;
    procedure SetA(const Value: ITestInterfacedClass);
    procedure SetB(const Value: ITestInterfacedClass);

  public
    property A: ITestInterfacedClass read GetA write SetA;
    property B: ITestInterfacedClass read GetB write SetB;
  end;


  { ITestInterfacedClass }
....

procedure SetProperty(aLeft: TObject {IInterface}; aNameProp: string; aRight: IInterface);
var
  RttiContext: TRttiContext;
  RttiType: TRttiType;
  RTTIProperty: TRttiProperty;
begin
  RttiContext := TRttiContext.Create;

  RTTIType := RttiContext.GetType(TTestInterfacedClass);
  RTTIProperty := RTTIType.GetProperty(aNameProp);
  if RTTIProperty.PropertyType.TypeKind = tkInterface then
    RTTIProperty.SetValue(aLeft, TValue.From<IInterface>(aRight));
end;

var
  obj1: TTestInterfacedClass;
  intf1, intf2, intf3: ITestInterfacedClass;

begin
  obj1 := TTestInterfacedClass.Create;
  intf1 := obj1;
  intf2 := TTestInterfacedClass.Create;
  intf3 := TTestInterfacedClass.Create;

  intf1.A := intf2;

  // intf1.B := intf3;
  SetProperty(obj1, 'B', intf3);

end.
```

I have to write an analog of
    intf1.B: = intf3;
or
    obj1.B = intf3;

using RTTI.

Is this possible?

UPD
It is work:

```
procedure SetProperty(aLeft: TObject; aNameProp: string; aRight: IInterface);
var
  RttiContext: TRttiContext;
  RttiTypeInterface: TRttiInterfaceType;
  RTTIProperty: TRttiProperty;
  Value: TValue;
begin
  RttiContext := TRttiContext.Create;

  RTTIType := RttiContext.GetType(aLeft.ClassType);
  RTTIProperty := RTTIType.GetProperty(aNameProp);
  if RTTIProperty.PropertyType.TypeKind = tkInterface then
  begin
    TValue.Make(@aRight, RTTIProperty.PropertyType.Handle, Value);
    RTTIProperty.SetValue(aLeft, Value);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: RTTIProperty.SetValue(aLeft, TValue.From<ITestInterfacedClass>(aRight as ITestInterfacedClass));
    

it is work, but inside SetProperty I do not want anything the nobility from ITestInterfacedClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that doesn't work because the Interface conversion code in RTTI.pas doesn't call QueryInterface.  If you put a TValue in with `TValue.From<IInterface>`, you can't convert it to a TValue of a different interface type, even if the interface supports that type.  Feel free to submit that to QC.

Creating the TValue with `TValue.From<ITestInterfacedClass>` does work, though.  But then you can't use the simple SetProperty routine.

Comment: TValue.Make(@aRight, RTTIProperty.PropertyType.Handle, Value);
    RTTIProperty.SetValue(aLeft, Value);